# Delay framework in Java with transaction atomicity in java

Tags: java, delay

I am replacing existing IBM MQ based system with new technology stack. In old system, a message is received on main MQ that is read by the process, there are some dependencies for the message to complete the processing, if they are not complete , the message will be put on delay MQ with message header containing expiry time, a custom made component will read such messages from delay queue and keep on putting it back to delay queue till it expires. Upon which it will put the message on main queue for processing. If JVM crashes in between, the message wont be lost.

I would like to have similar mechanism without using IBM MQ. How can I achieve it. Two design considerations: 
1. Main thread shouldn’t halt during delay
2. Message should not lost(while in delay) in any catastrophic event(JVM crash etc.)

Comment: check out apache camel, which has lot of utilities for this

Comment: Do you have any queuing layer in the new technology stack that you mentioned. It looks like you still want to continue doing what you are doing with your technical processes but use something that could replace IBM MQ i.e. queuing capability.

Comment: I am trying to replace IBM mq